# Multiple remote with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I used to code node.js applications with Eclipse and use git as VC. With the git plugin on Eclipse, I was able to declare multiple remote so that it was easy to push on github and deploy on heroku. As I am quite familiar with VS too, and as there is also a new plugin for nodej and VS now supports git natively, I wonder if (and how) it is possible to declare several remotes for the same solution ? I did not find how to do it yet...

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do so from the command-line, as in "[pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12795747/6309)":

```
git remote set-url origin --push --add user1@repo1
git remote set-url origin --push --add user2@repo2
git remote -v show
```

`git push` will push to `user1@repo1`, then push to `user2@repo2`.
**Leave out `--push` if you also want to be able to `git pull` from them too**.

You need to check if a Visual Studio "Publish" will actually do a multiple push, but at least the configuration of your local repo will be set to declare said multiple push destinations.